# How to make slider smoother in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

My slider jumps from one value to another. How can I make it movable in between the values or make it smoother in Flutter?

```dart
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RangeSlider(
          min: 1,
          max: 40,
          divisions: 4,
          onChanged: onChange,
          values: RangeValues((startValue ?? 1).toDouble(), (endValue ?? 40).toDouble()),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Beginner', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2),
            Text('Ameateur', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2),
            Text('Intermediate', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2),
            Text('Advanced', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2),
            Text('Professional', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

The `divisions` property makes it jump in 4 steps. Remove that and the slider will be fluent.

```dart
RangeSlider(
  min: 1,
  max: 40,
  // divisions: 4, // <-- remove this
  onChanged: onChange,
  values: RangeValues((startValue ?? 1).toDouble(), (endValue ?? 40).toDouble()),
),
```

## Update after question clarification

Question is actually about having the thumbs being fluent while still snapping to discrete points on the range slider. The Flutter widget does not provide an easy way to achieve that, so there are two options.

### Option 1: custom widget

The first is to create a new widget to get the exact behavior you need. This might be the best option if you need a lot of customisation.

### Option 2: hack the RangeSlider widget

Use the `onChangeEnd` callback in addition to the `onChanged` callback to update the position of the thumb correctly. The `onChanged` callback is used to make it fluent, while the `onChangeEnd` callback is used to snap the thumb to the closest discrete value based on a division count.

A possible implementation (the discretize method can possibly be shorter/improved):

```dart
class _RangeSliderExampleState extends State<RangeSliderExample> {
  double _startValue;
  double _endValue;
  static const double _minValue = 1;
  static const double _maxValue = 40;
  static const double _divisions = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RangeSlider(
      min: _minValue,
      max: _maxValue,
      onChanged: (values) {
        setState(() {
          _startValue = values.start;
          _endValue = values.end;
        });
      },
      onChangeEnd: (values) {
        setState(() {
          _startValue = _discretize(values.start, _divisions);
          _endValue = _discretize(values.end, _divisions);
        });
      },
      values: RangeValues((_startValue ?? 1).toDouble(),
          (_endValue ?? 40).toDouble()),
    );
  }

  double _discretize(double value, double divisions) {
    double x = value - _minValue;
    double range = _maxValue - _minValue;

    double result = x / range;
    return (result * divisions).round() / divisions * range + _minValue; 
  }
}
```

Comment: i added 4 default values in it after deleting division it will not stop on those values

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve exactly? It's not clear with this explanation.

Comment: I want my slider smooth with divisions not without it,

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 potential solutions to achieve what you want.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.